# Converting a set of tweets into vectors for clustering

Tags: python

I have a large set of tweets to which i plan to use cosine similarity to cluster the tweets. 
I found NLTK's GAAC to be good but how do i convert the tweets into vectors?

In `nltk.cluster.gaac.demo()` the data was passed as a vector 
`[array([ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]), array([ 0.4472136 ,  0.89442719]), array([ 0.89442719,  0.4472136 ]), array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 0.5547002 ,  0.83205029]), array([ 0.9486833 ,  0.31622777])]` 
For nltk gaac it says the input is `vectors` but i have plain text in the form of tweets.
How do i convert my set of tweets into vectors like this.

Comment: What is you data at the moment at what it should be? Please provide us more information.

Comment: For nltk gaac it says the input is vectors but i have plain text in the form of tweets.

Comment: I don't know anything about ntlk, but you should take a look at tf-idf if you want to do this kind of work with text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have vectors from text you need to "vectorize" your data.

You can look at the library sklearn to do this automatically.  But since you seem unsure about what vectorizing data actually means you should probably do it yourself.  What your vectors could represent is for example the occurrence of certain word, say "LOL" and "OMG".  But how you represent your tweeets in numbers is your choice, you can use your creativity and knowledge to find the best way. Then you can normalize the values to be between 0 and 1 afterwards (by computing their share of the total word count), but this is not necessarily necessary, depends on what you want to do with them later.

Using sklearn to vectorize is handy:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import *
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=100)
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
```

data is here a list of units (tweets, documents).  There are many ways of tweaking this procedure, but this gives you a sparse matrix back with vectorized data.  It is very handy for large document collections.

Comment: I doubt that NLTK will eat the `scipy.sparse` datastructures produced by scikit-learn, though.

Comment: try to make it a list of strings, e.g. ['this is first tweet','this is second tweet'].  you might benefit from looking at what it means to yield in python as well. otherwise look at the many examples from sklearn docs and inspect the data formats they input manually.